# "skip" button on Login UI does same as "OK" button with Facebook iOS SDK 3.11

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

When the Login UI is presented after calling

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler]
```

you are presented with a page that says to login to Facebook with two options: "ok" and "skip". If one has already authorized login before, clicking "skip" will return a state of **FBSessionStateOpen** and a **valid FBSession** back in code. Is it possible to have this "skip" button be differentiated from the "ok" button if the user has previously authorized Facebook (for example, on a previous install of the app)?